# Car hacking - e.g. auto closing windows when locking

Tags: car, obd, software

Im new to car hacking. I want to modify my car. The target is that the windows close automatically when i lock the car.

I found out that I can use the CAN2USB Device to connect the car to a linux machine.
Using the package can-utils (cansniffer, candump, cansend) I should be able to modify the car.

```
sudo apt-get install can-utils
```

But how should I start? Could you give me some tips for my first car hacking project?

Its a Mitsubishi Space Star Cross 2016

Comment: On many cars, if you hold the lock button down on the remote, it will close any open window. Have you checked?

Comment: Yes not on mine. I drive a Mitsubishi Space Star

Comment: So add the make, model and year to your post - it does help.

Comment: Added it: Mitsubishi Space Star Cross 2016